# Set virtualenv for python in textmate 2

Tags: python, virtualenv, textmate2

I'd like to work in my virtualenv from textmate 2, but i really have no idea on how to indicate text mate the env of python it has to use.

If anyone can help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to use a wrapper script, to first activate the virtualenv and then (within virtualenv) start the textmate2 process.

wrapper example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# load the virtual env
. $HOME/MY-VENV/bin/activate

# run the editor
/path/to/textmate "$@"
```

Comment: Where do I put that wrapper script?

Comment: @ustroetz: to any directory that is in PATH. I don't have MAC, but I guess /usr/local/bin/ will work

Answer (score 11):

If there's a project folder associated with your virtualenv, you could add a `.tm_properties` file that contains something like

```
TM_PYTHON = "$HOME/.virtualenvs/example/bin/python"
```

In fact, I might make a project template for virtualenvwrapper that does just that for all new projects.

To set it globally in TextMate 2, just add TM_PYTHON to the Variables section of the preferences. You should be able to set PYTHONPATH the same way (per-project or application-wide).

Comment: this is elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://code.zoia.org/2011/05/25/using-textmate-and-python-virtualenv/) essentially shows [Rob McBroom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993090) and [K.-Michael Aye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907386)'s answers in greater detail.

NOTE: It seems that you must disable any she-bangs (`#!/usr/bin/env python` in my case) for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

TM_PYTHON in the TM2 preferences for environment variables determines the Python to the preferred interpreter, but I did not find out yet, how to set the PYTHONPATH for TM2 yet.